# Regular expression check for some characters

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I want to check if a string contains both quotes for e.g. " ' and brackets (...) which occurs anywhere in the string.

For e.g.

```
string s = "The flora and fauna of Britain \"has been transported to almost every corner of the globe since colonial times\" (Plants and Animals of Britain, 1942: 8).";

string x = "Morris et al (2000: 47) state 'that the debate of these particular issues should be left to representative committees.'";
```

I came up with this:

```
Regex.IsMatch(x, @"(?<=""')[^\""]*(?=""')")
```

However, i think i'll try string.Contains as mentioned by @RB

@musefan, string s and y are both positive results and quotes have to be open and closed.

Comment: Why not just use `String.Contains`? What specifically about your requirements means you must use regex?

Comment: Do brackets have to open and close? Do quotes have to open and close? Please give more details about your rules, provide some test cases with both positive and negative results

Answer (score 0):

You can do the trick with `LINQ` using `Count` method:

```
string s = "The flora and fauna of Britain \"has been transported to almost every corner of the globe since colonial times\" (Plants and Animals of Britain, 1942: 8).";

bool isMatch = s.Count(c => c == '"') % 2 == 0  ||
               s.Count(c => c == '\'') % 2 == 0 ||
               (s.Count(c => c == '(') == s.Count(c => c == ')'));
```

If you want to ensure that string contains all characters `" ' ( )` just change `||` to `&&`